# Bootstrap 4 remove/ignore parent padding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure out how to remove top and bottom padding from **ul** element so that it is not affected by **-nav-** padding which is by default set at 8px. Here's the code:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand ">Welcome Brand</a>
        <form action="search.php" class="form-inline ml-auto" method="post">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control input-group-sm" type="text" name="searchTerm" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search...">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <input class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" type="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-2">
            <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link btn-outline-info">Browse Movies</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link btn-outline-info">Sign in</a></li>
          </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

I want the -ul- tag to have 0px padding while rest stays at 8px.

Comment: You could use the Bootstrap class `.p0` on the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's ".py-0" CSS rule can be added to your "ul" element to remove any top and bottom padding. This won't change the "nav" padding, however. If you're wanting to expand into the "nav" element's padding, one approach would be to apply negative top and bottom margins to your "li" elements:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-2 py-0">
   <li class="nav-item mr-2" style="margin-top: -8px; margin-bottom: -8px;">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link btn-outline-info">Browse Movies</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="margin: -8px 0;">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link btn-outline-info">Sign in</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```